# Pandas dataframe - Unique counts based on different conditions

Tags: pandas, dataframe, aggregate, pandas-groupby, unique

I have a dataframe like this

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTgbE.png)

I want to find out :

- unique viewers: 3
- unique viewers who reviewed movies: 2

I am able to do that using the following code:

```
movie['Viewer_ID'].nunique()

movie.loc[movie['watched']==1,:]['Viewer_ID'].nunique()
```

However, i was wondering if there is a better way to combined both in one, something like

```
movie.agg({'Viewer_id':'nunique'
      ,'watched': 'sum'
    })
```

is there a way i can write a conditional count within the agg function?

Comment: hi there, did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.groupby()`:

```
view_count = movie.groupby('Viewer_id').watched.sum()
```

Now `view_count` is a Series with viewer id as index and sum of watched as values. You can filter with:

```
filtered = view_count.loc[view.count > 0]
```